# Take variable from component

Tags: octobercms

i want take variables from component.
This is my code:

```
<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="galeryWraper">
<div class="row" >
   <h3>{{ galeria1.post.title }} {{ galeria1.post.description }}</h3>
        <div class="col-sm-8">

            {% component 'galeria1' %}

        </div>
      </div>
 </div>

 <!-- End Gallery -->
```

Galery works fine.
But galery title and desciption doesnt show up.

Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the property from the Twig partials for the component, utilize the `__SELF__` variable which refers to the Component object:

`{{ __SELF__.property('title') }}`

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately it doesnt work for me :(. Acording docs which are here:[link](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components) this should work: `{{ __SELF__.post.title }} ` where  `__SELF__  ` should be replaced with the component alias .

Comment: ok, so after investigating your code, it looks like you don't have "post" object assigned to the page, that means you should be able to access "title" property ```{{ galeria1.title }}```

Comment: Actually your way works :). The problem was that in this component which is "RJGallery" there is not "title" property but "lang" property which hold the name of gallery :).

Answer (score 3):

`post` must be defined in that component

```
public $post = null;
```

now within `onRun` or some how you need to assign it a value

```
public function onRun() {
    $this->post = 'value-text';
}
```

then only it will be available like

```
{{ galeria1.post }} 
// output 'value-text'
```

**so may be that post variable of yours is directly passed to page not assigned to component**

for example :

```
public function onRender()
{
    $this->page['post'] = 'some data';
}
```

OR

```
public function onRun()
{
    $this->page['post'] = 'some data';
}
```

**so this post is directly assigned to the page not to the component itself.**

**solution :**

you can do something like this

```
public $post= '';
public function onRender OR onRun() // choose method where data is added to page
{
    $this->post = 'some data';
    $this->page['post'] = $this->post;
}
```

Comment: In component code i have this:



        public function onRender()
        {
        $this->gallery = $this->page['gallery'] = GalleryModel::find($this-
        >property('idGallery'));

        // Inject all gallery properties to page.
        foreach ($this->getProperties() as $key => $value) {
            $this->page[$key] = $value;
        }
       }

So properties are in the "page"

How to access them by twig?

Comment: if properties are inside page then you can use them directly {{ id }} {{ title }} {{ description }}

Answer (score 3):

you can access those variable directly like this

```
{{ post.title }} {{ post.description }}
```

if they are set like below on your component

```
public function onRun(){
    $post = array();
    $post['title'] = 'some-title';
    $post['description'] = 'some-description';
    $this->page['post'] = $post;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hardik for formatting my answer. I am new to stackoverflow community.
BTW can you tell me why did you downvote the answer?

Comment: Snap !!, i don't want to down vote it, I didn't do it purposeful i was trying to move my mac and unfortunately clicked on that, but now there is no way to set it to Zero and I can not do up vote, sorry for that

Comment: and i also noticed that your answer is same as below one so its kind of duplication, try to avoid duplication in answer.

Comment: Oh no problem brother I will keep in my mind.
Thanks anyway